# For what values of $(x,y)$ are $xy,x/y$ and $x-y$ all equal?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For what values of $(x,y)$ are $xy,x/y$ and $x-y$ all equal?

Tried several times but unable to solve.

Comment: Are you trying to ask "for what values $(x,y)$ are $xy,x/y$ and $x-y$ all equal? I have difficulty guessing what -> and the x;y mean, otherwise.

Comment: yeah, you guessed it right.
anyways i have got the answer.

Comment: Congratulations, but let's make edits and spare future readers the pain of stumbling through the problem statement anyhow. The way it was written is probably why the post attracted a downvote immediately. Please take time to write clearly on future posts! Also, if you're having trouble picking tags, just leave a note in your post about it and people will help. The "quadratics" tag was not a good one to use. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want to solve $$\begin{align}xy &= x/y \\ xy &= x-y.\end{align}$$

If $x=0$, then the second equation becomes $0 = -y$, so $y=0$, which fails because then $x/y$ is undefined.  So $x\ne 0$.

Then divide the first equation  by $x$, giving $y=1/y$ so $y^2 = 1$.  Then $y=\pm1$.  Putting $y=1$ in the second equation we get $x = x- 1$, which is impossible. Putting $y=-1$ in the second equation we get  $-x = x+1$, which makes $x=-\frac12$.  So the only solution is $x=-\frac12, y=-1$ and the common  value of $xy$, $x-y$, and $x/y$ is $\frac12$.

Answer (score 1):

We know $y\not=0.$

$$xy=x/y\Rightarrow xy^2-x=0\Rightarrow x(y^2-1)=0\Rightarrow x=0\ \text{or}\ y=1\ \text{or}\ y=-1.$$

1) If $x=0$, then $xy=x-y$ leads $y=0$, which is a contradiction.

2) If $y=1$, then $xy=x-y$ leads $0=-1$, which is a contradiction.

3) If $y=-1$, then $xy=x-y$ leads $x=-1/2$.

On the other hand, if $(x,y)=(-1/2,-1)$, then $xy=x/y=x-y.$

Hence, the answer is $(x,y)=(-1/2,-1).$